# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' when i added a group

Tags: python, regex

I have this function:

```
def read_urls(filename):
    urls = open(filename, 'r').read()
    links = []
    for line in urls:
        url = (re.search(r"(?<=GET ).+(?= HTTP)", line).group(0))
        links.append("http://code.google.com"+url)
    links.sort()
    return links
```

but when I start the program I get this error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

can someone help me please?

Comment: Your call to `re.search` must not have found anything. What is `line`?

Comment: `for line in urls` isn't iterating over lines.

Comment: you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  including the inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs.   There are online tools for testing regex against input strings that might help you as you learn.

Comment: To expand on user2357112's comment -- `urls` ends up being a string containing the entire file contents.  And when you iterate over a string, you get each individual character.

Comment: Also, if you are not sure there will always be a match, use `m = re.search(...)`, `if m: ....`.

Answer (score 4):

This means that the regex you defined did not match the string you entered, this will create a None object and taking a group from a None object will raise the error you encountered. To prevent this us the following code:

```
match = re.search(r"(?<=GET ).+(?= HTTP)", line)
if match is not None:
    url = match.group(1)
else:
    #Some code you want if the regex does not match
```

edit: I would also recommend to compile your regex outside the for loop since this is much more effecient.

Comment: This is correct, however it doesn't address the _true_ error in his code, which was that he thought `line` was an entire url, when it was actually a _single character_ of a url.

Comment: Yes, if you want to iterate through lines like that you need `for line in open(filename, 'r')`

Comment: true that, did not see that, You could add .readlines() after the .read()